# Fetch nested object for a user in mongo db in a performant way

Tags: mongodb, performance, database-performance

**Below is my mongo db users collection**

```
// First Document
{
  username: 'adam',
  email: 'adam@gmail.com'
  sessions: {
    '121ED67': { pages: [] },
    '132EDD7': { pages: [] },
    '1111DD7': { pages: [] },
  }
}

// Second Document
{
  username: 'Levine',
  email: 'levine@gmail.com'
  sessions: {
    '121ED67': { pages: [] },
    '132EDD7': { pages: [] },
    '1111DD7': { pages: [] },
  }
}
.
.
.
so on...
```

Each document has 3 key-value pairs `username`, `email` and `sessions`. I have done Indexing on `email` using `createIndex({ email: 1 })`.

Here sessions can range between 1 to 1000 and they have deeply nested data inside them.

So now when sessions increase let's say adam has 200 sessions the document size also increases and when I fetch adam's document the whole document is transferred from database to frontend and it takes a lot of time when the document has many sessions because db resides on `cloud.mongodb.com` but backend server resides somewhere else.

When sessions are less in number let's say 8-10. It takes almost 2 to 4 seconds.

I want to find the document using `email` which already has indexing and then fetch only half of the sessions in one query for that user.

**For example**

If adam has 50 sessions. Fetch Adam's document but the sessions object should only contain 25 sessions which will decrease the size and make query faster and i can have that load more option in UI side which when clicked will make another query to show the remaining 25 or in other case I am open to suggestions.

**How can I increase the performance in my case ?**

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**

Comment: Is it a replica set or a sharded cluster? you can check this out in Atlas, if that's what you're using. Another important thing is, you can move your servers closer to the place where more data is fetch. if it's all over the world, then this is not useful. As was recommended below $project could be useful but in this case it seems to me that it won't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using all the session data when you get the document? If you're getting the whole document, it should be because you need the whole document.

If you don't need the whole document, only project the values you need to retrieve. Or, only store what you need in the document - e.g. the most recent session, with older sessions in a different collection.

Checkout the patterns at https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-a-summary - the bucket pattern combined with the outlier pattern might help.